# Can't read data simultaneously from the first three columns of a google sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm trying to read data from the first three columns of a [google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDDCZ.jpg) using gspread. The three columns that I'm interested in are `ID`,`NAME` and `SYMBOL`. The name of the sheet is `testFile`.

If I try like the following, I can get data from the first column.

```
client = authenticate()
sh = client.open("testFile")
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)

for item in worksheet.col_values(1):
    print(item)
```

However, I wish to parse the data from the three columns simultaneously. ***It would be better If I could read the values using column headers***.

I know I colud try like this to get the values, but this way I will end up getting quotaExceeded errors or something similar because of it's slow pacing.

```
for i in range(1, worksheet.row_count + 1):
   row = worksheet.row_values(i)
   if row[0]=='ID':continue
   print(row[0],row[1],row[2])
```

> How can I read data from the first three columns of a google sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for item in worksheet.col_values(1):
    print(item)
```

#### To:

```
values = worksheet.get_all_values()
obj = {}
for e in zip(*values):
    obj[e[0]] = list(e[1:])

print(obj)
```

- In this modification, all values are retrieved by one API call. And, the retrieved values are converted to an object as the key of the header title.

  - For example, when your sample Spreadsheet is used, you can retrieve the values of column "NAME" by `obj["NAME"]`.

Or,

#### To:

```
values = worksheet.get_all_records()
res = [e["NAME"] for e in values] # or e["ID"] or e["SYMBOL"]
print(res)
```

- In this modification, you can retrieve the values of column "NAME" can be retrieved.

#### References:

- [get_all_values](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.0.0/api.html?highlight=get_all_records()#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.get_all_values)
- [get_all_records](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.0.0/api.html?highlight=get_all_records()#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.get_all_records)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tanaike. I was doing like [this](https://pastebin.com/XN3FrEf0) to achieve that.

Comment: @MITHU Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.